# Vector-gaussian rate distortion theory with a covariance constraint

Tags: probability, statistics, reference-request, information-theory

Fix positive-definite $D\prec\Sigma \in \mathbb{R}^{n\times n}$.
$x[t]\overset{iid}\sim\mathcal{N}(0,\Sigma)$ for $t>0$.
Is the minimum entropy-rate $r$ known such that an encoding $\hat{x}$ typically has $\frac{1}{T}\sum_{t=1}^T (\hat{x}[t]-x[t])(\hat{x}[t]-x[t])' \preceq D$ for $T$ large enough?

I am trying to show $r=\min_S I(x;x+z)$ where $z\sim \mathcal{N}(0,S)$ and $S$ is among those where$\operatorname{var}(x-\mathbb{E}[x|x+z]) \preceq D$. The details are tricky and I'm not sure if this is the right answer.

---

If $\Sigma$ and $D$ are simultaneously diagonalizable then the information content of the source coding problem is identical to just $n$ independent scalar problems. I am having difficulty with the fact that $\Sigma$ and $D$ might not be simultaneously diagonalizable.

Can anyone help complete the argument, or find a flaw? A literature reference would be welcome too.

Comment: Encoding? entropy rate? Symbol $I(x,x+z)$? Your problem seems interesting but  the definitions are missing.

Comment: @GérardLetac Note the information theory tag, given which all these terms are standard.

Comment: Suppose I find an optimal test channel for $(I,\Sigma^{-1/2}D\Sigma^{-1/2})$. Then given the source observation, I can whiten with $\Sigma^{-1/2}$, execute the compression, and scale up by $\Sigma^{1/2}$ at the end. It's super tempting to guess that the resulting test channel is optimal for $(\Sigma, D)$. I don't quite see a proof, but might be worth chasing down?

Comment: Latest idea for an approach: (1) Prove a multivariate gaussian is the max-entropy distribution for a given mean vector and covariance matrix. (2) Look at the proof for the characterization of scalar rate distortion curves as optimization of a mutual information term. Adapt the proof to covariance-valued distortions. (3) Look at the mutual information optimization problem for a scalar gaussian source. Adapt it to the vector case using (1) and (2).

Comment: I think here's an argument for why the idea I outlined above is correct: let me define $Y = \Sigma^{-1/2}X$ and $\hat{Y} = \Sigma^{-1/2}\hat{X}$. Then note that the laws $p_{X,\hat{X}}$ and $p_{Y,\hat{Y}}$ are in bijection, $(X,\hat{X})$ satisfies the $D$-distortion condition iff $(Y,\hat{Y})$ satisfies the $\Sigma^{-1/2} D\Sigma^{-1/2}$-distortion condition, and $I(X;\hat{X}) = I(Y;\hat{Y})$ (since mutual information is invariant to the scaling unlike differential entropy; in any case, the difference can only be a function of $\Sigma$ alone, and not otherwise dependent on the laws).

Comment: (contd.) This yields exactly that if I know the optimal test channel for $(Y,\hat{Y}),$ then since the transform obtains the correct law of $X,$ the pullback is optimal for $(X,\hat{X})$. Of course once here you can diagonalise $\Sigma^{-1/2}D\Sigma^{-1/2},$ and proceed with optimal test channels for the orthogonal scalar laws, which IIRC is just adding Gaussian noise, and should be dealt with in Cover and Thomas for sure.